# Pentaho : Error while running pan.bat file in cmd line

Tags: pentaho, etl, kettle, data-integration

I am trying to run my .ktr file in cmd line. I have my data-integration setup in this path:

```
C:\Users\dhamodharan.a\Desktop\pdi-ce-4.4.0-stable\data-integration
```

and my .ktr file in this path:

```
C:\Users\dhamodharan.a\Desktop\test.krt
```

while am trying to run that in cmd line I am getting the following error

```
DEBUG: Using PENTAHO_JAVA_HOME
DEBUG: _PENTAHO_JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7
DEBUG: _PENTAHO_JAVA=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\java.exe
WARN 11-08 11:47:09,728 - Unable to load Hadoop Configuration from "file:///C:/
Users/dhamodharan.a/Desktop/pdi-ce-4.4.0-stable/data-integration/plugins/pentaho
-big-data-plugin/hadoop-configurations/mapr". For more information enable debug
logging.
INFO 11-08 11:47:09,759 - Pan - Start of run.
ERROR: No repository provided, can't load transformation.

C:\Users\dhamodharan.a\Desktop\pdi-ce-4.4.0-stable\data-integration>e:C:\Users\d
hamodharan.a\Desktop.test.ktr /level:Basic
```

I am trying to run an input excel file and make the output as excel. Do I also need to create repository for that?
If I try to create repository option I saw only for dbms not for excel.

Comment: Wow, why using such an old version?

Comment: @Codek actual i have made a big setup of 54 interfaces all that was made on penthao 4.4.0 ,so for that reason only am using ,still not i have time to upgrade

Comment: Can you please show the pan command you executed?

Comment: @codek , i made the setup good and now the command execute fine and good .

pan.bat /fil
e:"C:\Users\dhamodharan.a\Desktop\dhamu\test.ktr" /level:Basic

Anyway Thanks for your Response. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the environment variable PENTAHO_JAVA_HOME is set correctly and then it'll work.

For some reason the java install is not on your path. But if spoon works you must have it somewhere.

Comment: HI,thanks for your response , i did the PENTAHO_JAVA_HOME 

now this is the issue :
DEBUG: Using PENTAHO_JAVA_HOME
DEBUG: _PENTAHO_JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7
DEBUG: _PENTAHO_JAVA=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\java.exe
WARN 11-08 11:47:09,728 - Unable to load Hadoop Configuration from "file:///C:/
Users/dhamodharan.a/Desktop/pdi-ce-4.4.0-stable/data-integration/plugins/pentaho
-big-data-plugin/hadoop-configurations/mapr". For more information enable debug
logging.
INFO 11-08 11:47:09,759 - Pan - Start of run.
ERROR: No repository provided, can't load transformation.

Comment: Stange. Not sure about windows as I don't use it but try /file= rather than -file=...

Answer (score 0):

i did the environment variable for JAVA_HOME now pan.bat and kitchen.bat works fine.

here the command:

```
pan.bat /file:C:\Users\dhamodharan.a\Desktop\dhamu\test.ktr /level:Basic > C:\Users\dhamodharan.a\Desktop\dhamu\test.log
```

thanks